# Encrypting swap partition during install?

Tags: system-installation, encryption, swap

I manually made the partitions for a Xubuntu install, but see no option to encrypt the swap partition. Is there such a option?

The suggested duplicate question is not about encrypting swap during install.

Comment: Do you even need a swap partition? Ever since a kernel update in fall of 2017, swap files are just as fast as swap partitions, and swap files are far easier to manage for things like encryption. Only if you plan to add Hibernation or share one swap partition between dual-booted Linux installs does a swap partition make sense nowadays. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq explains more.

Comment: Let's say i want to have swap partition. Is there a way to encrypt it during install?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why encrypt the swap partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313564/why-encrypt-the-swap-partition)

Comment: Not really, because i want to encrypt the swap partition during the install, like the Calamares installer does, but i guess ubuntu installer can't do that.